# Download .xls file containing hebrew text

Tags: php, wordpress, export-to-excel

I have data in hebrew in my database and want to export that data as excell file on button click using php in wordpress. On downloading and opening the file the hebrew text display like ×ž×¤×¨×¥ ×©×œ×ž×”.

Here is my code:

```
         ob_start();
  date_default_timezone_set("Asia/Bangkok");
 $admin_added_customers = $wpdb->get_results
(
$wpdb->prepare
(
    "SELECT * FROM ".$wpdb->prefix . "record WHERE not_shipped = %d",
    0
)
);

function filterData(&$str)
{
    $str = preg_replace("/\t/", "\\t", $str);
    $str = preg_replace("/\r?\n/", "\\n", $str);
    if(strstr($str, '"')) $str = '"' . str_replace('"', '""', $str) . '"';
}

// file name for download
$fileName = "unshipped_cards_export_data" . date('Y-m-d') . ".xls";

// headers for download
header("Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-16LE");
header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
//header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
$keys = array("Name","Number","First Name", "Email","Address1","Address2","City","State","Zipcode","Country","Purchased On", "Expire On");
echo implode("\t", $keys) . "\n";

foreach($admin_added_customers as $row) {
    $customer = new WP_User($row->customer_id);

    echo mb_convert_encoding($customer->billing_first_name." ".$customer->billing_last_name,'utf-16','utf-8')."\t";
    echo $row->id."\t";
    echo $row->name."\t";
    echo $customer->user_email."\t";
    echo $customer->billing_address_1."\t";
    echo mb_convert_encoding($customer->billing_address_2,'utf-16','utf-8')."\t";
    echo mb_convert_encoding($customer->billing_city,'utf-16','utf-8')."\t";
    echo mb_convert_encoding($customer->billing_state,'utf-16','utf-8')."\t";
    echo $customer->billing_postcode."\t";
    echo WC()->countries->countries[$customer->billing_country]."\t";
    echo !empty($row->purchase_date) ? date("F j, Y", strtotime($row->purchase_date))."\t" : "\t";
    echo !empty($row->expiry_date) ? date("F j, Y", strtotime($row->expiry_date))."\t" : "\t";
    echo "\n";
}
```

Edit 1:

Here is the new code :

```
  header("Content-Disposition: attachment; filename=\"$fileName\"");
header("Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel");
echo "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body>";
$keys = array("Name","Number","First Name", "Email","Address1","Address2","City","State","Zipcode","Country","Purchased On", "Expire On");
echo implode("\t", $keys) . "\n";

foreach($admin_added_customers as $row) {
    $customer = new WP_User($row->customer_id);

    echo $customer->billing_first_name." ".$customer->billing_last_name."\t";
    echo $row->id."\t";
    echo $row->name."\t";
    echo $customer->user_email."\t";
    echo $customer->billing_address_1."\t";
    echo $customer->billing_address_2."\t";
    echo $customer->billing_city."\t";
    echo $customer->billing_state)."\t";
    echo $customer->billing_postcode."\t";
    echo WC()->countries->countries[$customer->billing_country]."\t";
    echo !empty($row->purchase_date) ? date("F j, Y", strtotime($row->purchase_date))."\t" : "\t";
    echo !empty($row->expiry_date) ? date("F j, Y", strtotime($row->expiry_date))."\t" : "\t";
    echo "\n";
}
echo "</body></html>";
```

This will solve the issue of hebrew text but now rather show data in tabular form, its showing whole data in first cell of excel.

Comment: The script converts some of the data from utf-8 to utf-16 because that data is in hebrew langauge and that need to be show as it is in excell file. when i open the file in excell it prompt a dailog asking "The file you are trying to open is in different format specified by the file extension.Do you want to open the file?" I click OK to open the file. Please suggest me what should i do to fix it?

Comment: I used file extension .csv still i face the same problem. I found a solution to  use "<html><head><meta http-equiv=\"Content-Type\" content=\"text/html; charset=utf-8\" /></head><body>" before my loop. This fixes the hebrew text issue but the whole code is now showing first cell of excel.

Comment: See the Edit 1 code above.